# Polynomials that are factored to equal a constant term and their derivatives.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Suppose I have a polynomial satisfying the condition

$$\prod_{i = 1}^{r}(z - a_i) = n$$

where all $r, a_1, \dots, a_r, n \in \mathbb{N}$ are non-zero and $r$ is assumed greater than $2$.

Letting $z \in \mathbb{C}$ allows for the definition of a polynomial $P(z)$ with integer coefficients where

$$P(z) = z^r + \cdots + c_1z + c_0$$

and

$$\frac{dP(z)}{dz} = rz^{r - 1} + \cdots + c_1.$$

The constants may be given in terms of $a_1, \dots, a_r, n \in \mathbb{N}$ above. I have two questions about how to interpret this and what I am allowed to do from a mathematical operations standpoint.

The first question refers to the fact that in a sense this polynomial is already factored, so am I allowed to take the derivative of the L.H.S.? this would give

$$\frac{d}{dz}\prod_{i = 1}^{r}(z - a_i) = \frac{d}{dz}(n).$$

Since $n$ is assumed to be a constant it would then follow that

$$\frac{d}{dz}\prod_{i = 1}^{r}(z - a_i) = 0.$$

Expanding out the polynomial shows

$$\frac{d}{dz}\prod_{i = 1}^{r}(z - a_i) = \frac{d}{dz}(z^r + \cdots + c_1z + (-1)^r\prod_{i = 1}^{r}a_i) = 0$$

where it follows that

$$\frac{d}{dz}\prod_{i = 1}^{r}(z - a_i)= rz^{r - 1} + \cdots + c_1 = 0.$$

Sinse

$$\frac{dP(z)}{dz} = rz^{r - 1} + \cdots + c_1,$$ it follow that

$$\frac{dP(z)}{dz} = 0.$$

However, this implies that the derivative of $P(z)$ is equal to $0$ for all $z$. How are we to interpret this and use it to find general solutions, or at least a relationship between roots? One thought I had was to take $\ln$ of both sides since

$$\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)} = \frac{d}{dz}\ln{P(z)}$$

and use the fact that

$$\frac{d}{dz}\ln(\prod_{i = 1}^{r}(z - a_i)) = \frac{d}{dz}\ln(n).$$

This allows for

$$\frac{1}{z - a_1} + \frac{1}{z - a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{z - a_r} = 0.$$

However, I do not see a way that this would be useful.

Comment: $\prod (z-a_i)=n$ is an equation, which is true for some $z,$ not all $z,$ so you can't differentiate both sides. You would need the equality for all $z$ to differentiate both sides.

Comment: If $\prod_{i=1}^r(z-a_i) = n$, meaning either that the polynomials are equal or that the equation is true for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $r=0$ and $n=1$. So the very beginning of your question is confusing.

Comment: Why must we have $r>2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if the polynomial $P$ is constant, we would actually expect the derivative to be zero.

Your last equation just rearranges this fact. Multiply it through by $P(z)$, then you have the differential of $P(z)$ on the LHS (via the product rule).